# Instance variable not initialized on TravisCI

Tags: ruby, travis-ci, minitest

I have a problem running my test suite on TravisCI. It used to be green but since some time I'm getting a buttload of messages like:

```
/home/travis/build/PuzzleFlow/tochtli/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bunny-2.3.0/lib/bunny/cruby/socket.rb:37: warning: instance variable @__bunny_socket_eof_flag__ not initialized
```

As a result, the log exceeds 4MB of size and the job fails (even though when I read full log, the tests are passed). Since this is an external lib, I can't change its code. I checked with many versions of bunny/amq-protocol, but it seems unrelated. I also don't use `rspec` for this, I use `minitest`.

What can I do to avoid those messages and get clean build output?

**See:**

- [example build](https://travis-ci.org/PuzzleFlow/tochtli/jobs/117348749)
- [travis.yml](https://github.com/PuzzleFlow/tochtli/blob/master/.travis.yml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
/home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby -W -w -I"lib:lib:test" -I"/home/travis/build/PuzzleFlow/tochtli/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.1/lib" "/home/travis/build/PuzzleFlow/tochtli/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-11.1.1/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb" "test/**/*_test.rb"
```

Here the `-w` means that you are running in warning mode. See `ruby --help` for more explanation

It looks like your project has an updated version of `rake`. `rake/testtask` seems to be using the warning option by default. Try setting it to false: https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/testtask.rb#L51

EDIT:

It seems like you also need to set `verbose = false` because of https://github.com/ruby/rake/blob/master/lib/rake/testtask.rb#L131

The lines in your Rakefile should read:

```
Rake::TestTask.new(:test) do |test|
  test.libs << 'lib' << 'test'
  test.pattern = 'test/**/*_test.rb'
  test.verbose = false
  test.warning = false
end
```